# Quartz Composer Viewer Zoom

Tags: quartz-composer

I'm not sure how I did it, but for some reason, the coordinate system is completely out of wack. Everything appears completely zoomed in, and it's the same outside of Quartz Composer too, so something strange is up. Is there any normal way that this could happen, or do I have some sort of corruption somewhere?
[image: My project]

All of this should work correctly. I've followed the logic many times, and there really is no reason it should appear all zoomed in like it does. You'll notice I have two custom patches that I wrote myself. That "shouldn't" cause any issues, but you never know...

I just discovered that the cause of the problem is my custom AppleScript patch. The patch works as intended, but for some reason when it's loaded, the composition bugs out like that, and I can't fix it until I unload the patch from Quartz Composer (simply deleting it from the composition doesn't work). Clearly this is some sort of corruption issue, but I can't for the life of me figure out what the issue is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hah, just noticed I had two clears. Got rid of it, but obviously that didn't fix anything. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing your sound patch ? I sometime have the same trouble with consumers that are not behaving as expected.

You might want to try putting it behind your "clear" patch too...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "Render in Image" patch, it usually makes the zoom fixed. Also there is the Origami plugin by Facebook's design team, that uses the "phone" patch to fix the size of all the composition into a screen.